# Page crash when insert VisualState.Setters Property for "Label.Text"

Tags: xaml, .net-maui, visualstatemanager

I have one .NET MAUI xaml-page with a Label and Switch.
When i try to use `VisualState`-setters for change label text value on switch on/off, it work with emulator and in phone-debugger mode, but when i download it into my android phone the page crash when try to open!!
This is the part of code for reproduce the problem:

```
    <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Spacing="7" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="50">
                                
                <!-- Automatic-Manual -->
                <VerticalStackLayout Margin="2" >
                    <Label x:Name="LblAutoMan" Text="Automatic" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="65"/>
                    <Switch IsToggled="True" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="10">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState Name="On">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="Green" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="LblAutoMan" Property="Label.Text" Value="Automatic" /> 
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState Name="Off">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="Red" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="LblAutoMan" Property="Label.Text" Value="Manual" /> 
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Switch>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
               
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
```

If i comment both two rows: `<Setter TargetName="LblAutoMan"`

Can someone resolve this bug?

Comment: Please include the exception in your title or edit post `InvalidOperationException: VisualStateGroup Names must be unique` it will be helpful for futur readers.

Comment: I also recommend adding XAMLCompilation to avoid such naughty errors : `[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` in your MAUIProgram class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/xamlc

Comment: isn't it enabled by default (template) in maui ?

Comment: @Cfun Yeah seems that its an issue of dispute if this should be enabled on not.. Weird because XF did it by default after a while so why not? By default its not according to MS docs at least

Comment: from the docs "XAML compilation is enabled by default in .NET MAUI apps" but searching my entier solution for `XamlCompilationOptions` i don't find

Comment: @Cfun EXACTLY!!!!!

Comment: @Cfun Not sure if you are interested but I have started a discussion about this, Lets see if someone responds :D https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/10070

Answer (score 7):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8003) you need to enclose your `<VisualStateGroup>` inside a `<VisualStateGroupList>` tag:

```
<HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Spacing="7" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="50">
                            
    <!-- Automatic-Manual -->
    <VerticalStackLayout Margin="2" >
        <Label x:Name="LblAutoMan" Text="Automatic" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="65"/>
        <Switch IsToggled="True" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="10">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState Name="On">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="Green" />
                                <Setter TargetName="LblAutoMan" Property="Label.Text" Value="Automatic" /> 
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState Name="Off">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="Red" />
                                <Setter TargetName="LblAutoMan" Property="Label.Text" Value="Manual" /> 
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                  </VisualStateGroupList>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Switch>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

Comment: I try this solution but the problem still the same!

Comment: I have tested your exact same code and then apply the solution the issue disappraed. possibly try clean solution and rebuild

Comment: this problem appears only when i download the app into my android phone and then run it on the device. In all the other cases (running from v.s. in my  windows machine, running from v.s. in android emulator, running from v.s. in my android local phone) it works without this problems!

Comment: 2 years later and the documentation still excludes that list in their examples, as in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/checkbox?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: @HeribertoLugo check [visual-states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states?view=net-maui-8.0), you know that you can provide suggestions on the documentation in [this repo](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/blob/main/docs/user-interface/controls/checkbox.md).

Comment: @Cfun that very link you posted also shows examples without the list element. looks same as link i posted. and if you copy and paste the example from the docs i posted, you will get an error, and end up here for the fix. i'll submit a issue on the repo you posted.